# XPath - Select text() in between two DIV identified by matching text in it

Tags: html, css, xpath, scrapy

I have this HTML,

```
<div id="General" class="detailOn">
    <div class="tabconstraint"></div>
    <div id="InstitutionMain" class="detailseparate">
        <div id="InstitutionMain_divINFORight" style="float:right;width:40%"></div>
        <div style="font-weight:bold;padding-top:6px">Special Learning Opportunities</div>
        Distance learning opportunities<br>

        <div style="font-weight:bold;padding-top:6px">Student Services</div>
        Remedial services<br>
        Academic/career counseling service<br>

        <div style="font-weight:bold;padding-top:6px">Credit Accepted</div>
        Dual credit<br>
        Credit for life experiences<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract

```
text() = between [Div/text() = "Special Learning Opportunities</div>
        Distance learning opportunities"] and [div/text()="Student Services"]
```

similarly for other divs

I tried this code which gives me all text following the identified div,

```
div[1]/div[contains(text(),"Special Learning Opportunities")]/following-sibling::text()
```

While this code gives me the all text before the div

```
div[1]/div[contains(text(),"Student Services")]/preceding-sibling::text()
```

Is there a way to get exactly all the text in between specified DIVs.
Thanks in advance.

I am using python 2.x and scrapy for crawling.

Note: My current method:-
using these three xpaths

```
item['SLO']=site.select('div[1]/div[contains(text(),"Special Learning Opportunities")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
item['SS']=site.select('div[1]/div[contains(text(),"Student Services")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
item['CA']=site.select('div[1]/div[contains(text(),"Credit Accepted")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
```

I get three items like this,

```
item['SLO']=['Distance learning opportunities','Remedial services',' Academic/career counseling service','Dual credit','Credit for life experiences']
item['SS']=['Remedial services',' Academic/career counseling service','Dual credit','Credit for life experiences']
item['CA']=['Dual credit','Credit for life experiences']
```

and then I work on python list to get what i want,

But I think there should be q quicker way in XPath to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, not so classy as the previous answer, but hey - atleast it works! :-)

```
div[1]//div[contains(text(),"Special Learning Opportunities")]/following-sibling::node()[position() <= count( div[1]//div[contains(text(),"Student Services")]/following-sibling::node()) + 1]
```

Comment: Awesome. As being a newbie in XPath, took little time to understand. but worked great.

Answer (score 4):

You can  directly translate "text between a and b" into XPath as "text()[previous-sibling = a and next-sibling = b]"

I.e.:

```
//text()[(preceding-sibling::div[1]/text() = "Special Learning Opportunities") and (following-sibling::div[1]/text() = "Student Services")]
```

should work.

(although it failed  when I tested it, but it seems to be a bug in my XPath interpreter)

Comment: I had two typos, they are fixed now. But it still doesn't work. (I tried three XPath interpreter: 1. returns nothing, but also returns nothing at `//text()/preceding-sibling::div`, 2. returns nothing, but that one also returns nothing at `//text()`,  3. fails with an "invalid xml" message)

Comment: found the bug in my interpreter (following/-sibling and preceding-sibling axes weren't allowed for text nodes), now it works for me

Answer (score 1):

You may try this..

```
//div[contains(text(),"Special Learning Opportunities")]//following-sibling::text()[./following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'Student Services')]]
```